# BeautifulSoup returns urls of pages on same website shortened

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, httplib2

My code for reference:

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
response, content = h.request('http://csb.stanford.edu/class/public/pages/sykes_webdesign/05_simple.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
urls = []
for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    urls.append(tag['href'])
responses = []
contents = []
for url in urls:
    try:
        response1, content1 = h.request(url)
        responses.append(response1)
        contents.append(content1)
    except:
        pass
```

The idea is, I get the payload of a webpage, and then scrape that for hyperlinks. One of the links is to yahoo.com, the other to 'http://csb.stanford.edu/class/public/index.html'

However the result I'm getting from BeautifulSoup is:

```
>>> urls
['http://www.yahoo.com/', '../../index.html']
```

This presents a problem, because the second part of the script cannot be executed on the second, shortened url. Is there any way to make BeautifulSoup retrieve the full url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the link on the webpage is actually of that form. The HTML from the page is:

`<p>Or let's just link to <a href=../../index.html>another page on this server</a></p>`

This is called a relative link.

To convert this to an absolute link, you can use `urljoin` from the standard library.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin  # Python3

urljoin('http://csb.stanford.edu/class/public/pages/sykes_webdesign/05_simple.html`,
        '../../index.html')
# returns http://csb.stanford.edu/class/public/index.html
```

Comment: of course, thank you. I may include the url join part in the exceptions.

Comment: on further thought, I won't bother, it's only specific to a single webpage and not worth bothering with really